# How to use popen() in a shared library?

Tags: c, debian, shared-libraries, popen, preload

When attempting to use popen() in a shared library and preloading it via LD_PRELOAD or /etc/ld.so.preload, the process gets stuck in an infinite loop with either an error message saying that the shared library cannot be preloaded, or the system just freezes and needs to be rebooted, depending on the code.

Please note that compiling not as a shared library (`gcc test.c; ./a.out`) will work without error.

If it is helpful, I am running a fresh install of Debian on VirtualBox:

> Linux debian 3.16.0-4-586 #1 Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) i686
>   GNU/Linux

Okay, so this code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor, visibility("hidden")))
void init()
{
    FILE *fp = popen("/usr/bin/id", "r");
    pclose(fp);
}
```

Results in the first case:

```
root@debian:/mnt/group/hcfrk# gcc test.c -o test.so -std=c99 -shared -fPIC
root@debian:/mnt/group/hcfrk# LD_PRELOAD=./test.so whoami
ERROR: ld.so: object './test.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object './test.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object './test.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object './test.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
# For eternity.
```

This code:

```
...
#include <limits.h>
...
{
    FILE *fp = popen("/usr/bin/id", "r");

    if(!fp)
        puts("Error.\n");

    char buf[PATH_MAX];

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))
        printf("%s\n", buf);

    pclose(fp);    // Never gets here: VM just freezes.
}
```

Results in the second case (the system freezes). I suspect it is because of the while loop not ending and causing pclose() to not be called, as the first code example will freeze the system without pclose() as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is that your library gets preloaded before the rest of libc is loaded, so you can't call those functions in your `init()` function.

Comment: @Barmar well if his `init()` function links to libc, then would loading libc be part of the preload?

Comment: OP I'm pretty sure you have to put `-shared -fPIC` before the .c file

Comment: Also, have you tried replacing the contents of `init()` with a simple `printf` so you can deduce that it may not be `popen()` breaking?

Comment: `-shared -fPIC` before didn't change the output. Also, yes, I have tried `printf` and other libc functions, and it works fine. This is part of a bigger project of mine, where I am hooking functions in libc and other shared libs. This `popen` code in isolation is problematic (it's not an issue caused by my project). Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't you forkbombing here? Constructor in `LD_PRELOAD` will cause `/usr/bin/id` to execute itself forever (as each new instance will get get your library preloaded), most probably halting your machine. You should probably `unsetenv` before popening.

Comment: Ah, dude! Thank you! That makes sense. I don't know how that slipped my mind. I have been trying to figure this out for days now. I feel silly.

Comment: Welcome to world of runtime instrumentation ;)